# Error: How to save details to in my firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried so many time to implement to search my android Firebase database to my mobile app but its not working. I attached my source code in here. In my case I have to save my details in firebase its not saving in my firebase realtime database. Please help me. Now im updated my source code but still this error.

```
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class AppointmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText name, pnumber, email, sdate, stime;
    private Button send, cancel;
    private Spinner sspinner, dspinner;


    private static final String TAG="BookingActivity";

    private TextView mDisplayDate;
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;

    private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;
    //time
    TextView chooseTime;
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;
    Calendar calendar;
    int currentHour;
    int currentMinute;
    String amPm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_appointment);

        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        pnumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phoneno);
        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mail);
        sdate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.s_date);
        stime = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.s_time);
        sspinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.s_spinner);
        dspinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.d_spinner);
        cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(AppointmentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        //date
        mDisplayDate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.s_date);

        mDisplayDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
                int year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog dialog=new DatePickerDialog(
                        AppointmentActivity.this,
                        android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                        mDateSetListener,
                        year, month, day);
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        mDateSetListener=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                month=month + 1;
                Log.d(TAG, "onDateSet: mm/dd/yyy: " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year);

                String date=month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
                mDisplayDate.setText(date);
            }
        };


        //time
        chooseTime=findViewById(R.id.s_time);
        chooseTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                currentHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                currentMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                timePickerDialog=new TimePickerDialog(AppointmentActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minutes) {
                        if (hourOfDay >= 12) {
                            amPm="PM";
                        } else {
                            amPm="AM";
                        }
                        chooseTime.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", hourOfDay, minutes) + amPm);
                    }
                }, currentHour, currentMinute, false);

                timePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

        mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getInstance().getReference();




        private void saveData() {
            FirebaseUser mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            DatabaseReference mUserReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            HashMap<String, String> registerHash = new HashMap<>();
            registerHash.put(mFirebaseDatabase.push(), "Your value");
            registerHash.put(mFirebaseDatabase.push(), "Your value");
            registerHash.put(mFirebaseDatabase.push(), "Your value");
            registerHash.put(mFirebaseDatabase.push(), "Your value");
            registerHash.put(mFirebaseDatabase.push(), "Your value");
            mUserReference.setValue(registerHash).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(CompleteProfileActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(CompleteProfileActivity.this, "" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with this code? What is not working?

Comment: its not saving my firebase realtime database

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple just do like this:-

```
    private void saveData() {
FirebaseUser mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
DatabaseReference mUserReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            HashMap<String, String> registerHash = new HashMap<>();
            registerHash.put(mFirebaseDatabase.push().getKey(), "Your value");
           registerHash.put(mFirebaseDatabase.push().getKey(), "Your value");
           registerHash.put(mFirebaseDatabase.push().getKey(), "Your value");
           registerHash.put(mFirebaseDatabase.push().getKey(), "Your value");
           registerHash.put(mFirebaseDatabase.push().getKey(), "Your value");
            mUserReference.setValue(registerHash).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(CompleteProfileActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(CompleteProfileActivity.this, "" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: first of all set you value instead of "Your Value" And according to your code you are not calling the save data method

Answer (score 0):

Change your click listener with this.

```
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String names = name.getText().toString();
            String number = pnumber.getText().toString();
            String sdates = sdate.getText().toString();
            String emails = email.getText().toString();
            String sspinners = (String) sspinner.getSelectedItem();
            String dspinners = (String) dspinner.getSelectedItem();
            String mDisplayDate = sdate.getText().toString();
            String chooseTime = stime.getText().toString();

            Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
            childUpdates.put("names/", names);
            childUpdates.put("number/", number);
            childUpdates.put("sdates/", sdates);
            childUpdates.put("emails/", emails);
            childUpdates.put("sspinners/", sspinners);
            childUpdates.put("dspinners/", dspinners);
            childUpdates.put("mDisplayDate/", mDisplayDate);
            childUpdates.put("chooseTime/", chooseTime);
            mFirebaseDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
        }
    });
```

Comment: same error. shall I share my source project with you

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 DatabaseReference test = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

 HashMap<String, String> registerHash = new HashMap<>();
 registerHash.put(test.push().getKey(), "Your value");
 registerHash.put(test.push().getKey(), "Your value");

 test.setValue(registerHash);
```